# How can I return the mode that appeared first in an array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, for-loop, frequency

I want to create a function that will return the number with highest frequency(mode). For example: if array contains **[10, 4, 5, 2, 4]** the output should be **4**. If there is more than one mode, I want to return the one that appeared in the array first (ie. **[10,2,5, 4, 5, 2, 4]** should return **2** because it appeared first. If there is no mode, I want to return -1. The array will not be empty. Below is my attempt

```
function Mode(arr){
    if(arr == undefined || arr.length == 0){
        return
    }
    const number_to_frequency = {};
    let number_with_overall_highest_frequency = 0;
    let overall_highest_frequency = 0;

    for(index in arr) {
        const number = arr[index];
   
        if(number_to_frequency[number]) {
            number_to_frequency[number] += 1;
        } else {
            number_to_frequency[number] = 1;
        }
   
        let updated_frequency = number_to_frequency[number]
   
        if(overall_highest_frequency < updated_frequency) {
            number_with_overall_highest_frequency = number;
            overall_highest_frequency = updated_frequency;
        }
   
  }
 
  if(overall_highest_frequency == 1){
      return -1
  }
  return number_with_overall_highest_frequency;
};
console.log(Mode([10,2,5, 4, 5, 2, 4])) //5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only need the first one that its repeated you can try this approach

```
  const checkMode = (array = []) => {

    const duplicated = array.find(value => array.filter(_value => value === _value).length > 1)

    return duplicated >= 0 ? duplicated: -1
  }

checkMode([10,2,5, 4, 5, 2, 4])
```

Comment: @miguel-hidago Can you explain your code? I got lost at some point

Comment: So  the condition of the find is the result of the filter of ```[10,2,5, 4, 5, 2, 4] ``` by the number of each loop of the find method,  the first one that filter lenght is above 1 will  evaluate ``true`` and then will return the number of the actual iteration in the example case is 2